# Prove that meas$(A)\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ be a nondecreasing continuous function and let $$A:=\{x\in\mathbb R : \exists\quad y>x\:\text{ such that }\:f(y)-f(x)>y-x\}.$$

I've already proved that:

a) if $(a,b)$ is a bounded open interval contained in $A$, and $a,b\not\in A$, then $f(b)-f(a)=b-a.$

b)$A$ contains no half line.

What remains is to prove that the Lebesgue measure of $A$ is less or equal than $1$. I've tried to get estimates on the integral of $\chi_A$ but i went nowhere further than just writing down the integral. I'm not sure whether points a) and b) are useful, but i've reported them down for the sake of completeness so you can use them if you want.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Observe that in your result a) you also have $f(b) - f(a) \leq 1$ due to the range of $f$.

Comment: But this doesn't help me unfortunately.. Of course i thought that fact was useful but i don't know how to link it to a proof of the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

(c) show that $A$ is open

(d) Any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of countably many disjoint open intervals $\amalg (a_i,b_i)$. The Lebesgue measure is equal to $\sum (b_i - a_i)$. Now apply item (a) and the fact that $f$ is non-decreasing.